# which is the inverse of this linear application?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading some examples about linear functionals from the book Introductory functional analysis with applications of Kreysig and one of the examples states the following

Let $L:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$

$$L[f(x)]=\int_{0}^{x}f(s)ds$$ that is linear and $R(T)=C^{1}[0,1]$ s.t $L(0)=0$.

My question is how can I can calculate $L^{-1}: R(T)\rightarrow C[0,1] $

I could give some suggestion ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it bijective? It would mean every continuous function on $[0,1]$  is differentiable!

Comment: Sorry i just realized biyectiva appears to be Spanish spelling of English bijective.

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072929/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: fundamental theorem of calculus.

Hint 2: if $f\in C^1([0,1])$ and $f(0)=0$, then we can consider $f'\in C([0,1])$ and also
$$
g(x)=\int_0^x f'(s)\,ds
$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f'=g'$ and $g=L(f')$, so…

Comment: Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus I'd have to $L'[f(x)]=f(x)$

Comment: @AlexPozo Certainly not: $L'[f(x)]$ makes no sense.

Comment: So how should use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to determine $L^{-1}$

Comment: @AlexPozo The extended hint says that $L^{-1}f=f'$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I had not noticed the behavior of a function in $C^1[0,1]$, with your explanation was very simple to determine $L^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

The function is not bijective, as for any function $f$ in $C[0,1]$ $L(f(0))=\int\limits_{0}^{0}f(s)ds=0$, so the function $x \to x+1$ does not have a preimage, as $0+1=1$